# Extract only day and month from date in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I need to extract day and month from the datetime array in Matlab. I know I can extract day() and month() separately. I just want to display x-axis with day-month format, like 25/08 or 25-Aug. 
Is there any quick way?

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: The short answer (summarized from linked duplicates) is to plot your data versus the datetime values, then use `xtickformat` to format the labels.